# Difference between _JAVA_OPTIONS, JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I thought it would be great to have a comparison between `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`.
I have been searching a bit for one, but I cannot find anything, so I hope we can find the knowledge here on Stackoverflow.

`JAVA_OPTS` is included for completeness. It is not part of the JVM, but there is a lot of questions about it out in the wild.

### What I know:

So far I have found out that:

- **`JAVA_OPTS`** is not used by the JDK, but by a bunch of other apps (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933300/)).
- **`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`** and **`_JAVA_OPTIONS`** are ways to specify JVM arguments as an environment variable instead of command line parameters.

  - The are picked up by at least `java` and `javac`
  - They have this precedence:

    1. `_JAVA_OPTIONS` (overwrites the others)
    2. Command line parameters
    3. `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` (is overwritten by the others)

### What I would like to know

- Are there any official documentation comparing `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and `_JAVA_OPTIONS`
- Are there any other differences between `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and `_JAVA_OPTIONS` (except from precedence).
- Which executables pick up `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and `_JAVA_OPTIONS` (in addition to `java` and `javac`)
- Any limitation on what can be included on `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and `_JAVA_OPTIONS`

### Official Documentation

I have not been able to find any documentation about `_JAVA_OPTIONS`. [The documentation for `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#tooloptions) does not shed much light on the difference:

> Since the command-line cannot always be accessed or modified, for example in embedded VMs or simply VMs launched deep within scripts, a JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable is provided so that agents may be launched in these cases. 
> ...

## Example script

This is the code I used to figure this out. Console output is included as comments:

```
export JAVA_OPTS=foobar
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS= 
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx512m -Xms64m"

java -version                          
# Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: 
# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m -Xms64m
# java version "1.7.0_40"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.1) (suse-3.41.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b50, mixed mode)

javac -version
# Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: 
# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m -Xms64m
# javac 1.7.0_40

export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx1 -Xms1"
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx512m -Xms64m"
javac -version
# Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1 -Xms1
# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m -Xms64m
# javac 1.7.0_40

export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx512m -Xms64m"
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1 -Xms1"
javac -version
# Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m -Xms64m
# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1 -Xms1
# Error occurred during initialization of VM
# Too small initial heap

export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xmx1 -Xms1"
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=
java -Xmx512m -Xms64m -version
# Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1 -Xms1
# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: 
# java version "1.7.0_40"
# OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.1) (suse-3.41.1-x86_64)
# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b50, mixed mode)

export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1 -Xms1"
java -Xmx512m -Xms64m -version
# Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: 
# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1 -Xms1
# Error occurred during initialization of VM
# Too small initial heap
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781405/information-about-java-options

Comment: And since **JDK 9+**, there's `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` as the preferred replacement, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52986487/537554

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You have pretty much nailed it except that these options are picked up even if you start JVM in-process via a library call.

The fact that `_JAVA_OPTIONS` is not documented suggests that it is not recommended to use this variable, and I've actually seen people abuse it by setting it in their `~/.bashrc`. However, if you want to get to the bottom of this problem, you can check the source of Oracle HotSpot VM (e.g. [in OpenJDK7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp)).

You should also remember that there is no guarantee other VMs have or will continue to have support for undocumented variables.

**UPDATE 2015-08-04:** To save five minutes for folks coming from search engines, `_JAVA_OPTIONS` trumps command-line arguments, which in turn trump `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`.

Comment: sorry as a non native english speaker, "_JAVA_OPTIONS  trumps command-line arguments, which in turn trump JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS " is very unclear what does it mean.

Comment: @yang-yang In this context "trumps" means "takes precedence over".  So if  _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dfoo=bar" and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfoo=sna" the end result would be that System.getProperty("foo") would return "bar".

Answer (score 65):

There is one more difference: `_JAVA_OPTIONS` is Oracle specific. IBM JVM is using `IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS` instead. This was probably done to be able to define machine-specific options without collisions. `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is recognized by all VMs.

Answer (score 43):

`JAVA_OPTS` have [no special handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241743/how-do-i-use-the-java-opts-environment-variable) in JVM at all.

And according to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4971166 the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is included in standard JVMTI specification, does better handling of quoted spaces and should be always preferred instead of undocumented Hotspot-specific `_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

Also beware that using these [prints additional message to stdout that can't be suppressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683715/suppressing-the-picked-up-java-options-message).

---

As @ryenus noted, since JDK 9+, there's `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable as the preferred replacement, see [What is the difference between JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS when using Java 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52986487/537554)