# How to set default garbage collector in Java 9+?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-9

Is there any system-wide or account-wide configuration file I can use? I don't want to use MAVEN_OPTS because forked java processes won't pick it up then.

There is a lib/jvm.cfg, though I don't understand its semantics or whether it can be used for that purpose at all.

Comment: Can you use alias?  For example: `alias java='java –XX:+UseG1GC'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \_JAVA\_OPTIONS JAVA\_TOOL\_OPTIONS and JAVA\_OPTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no system-wide way to set JVM flags for all Java processes.  There are various environment variables that are conventionally used by 3rd-party tools.  Some of them are described here:

- [Difference between _JAVA_OPTIONS JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS and JAVA_OPTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts)

However, these do not apply when you launch an application directly using the `java` command.

The "jvm.cfg" file does not help.  It implements an (undocumented) mechanism for configuring the `java` command's "known JVMs" and the JVM options that select them.  (For details, refer to `src/java.base/share/native/libjli/java.c` in the OpenJDK 11 source tree.)

---

This leaves you with clunky / kludgy / fragile alternatives like:

- defining `java` as a shell function or alias
- writing a wrapper script for the `java` command and putting it on your PATH ahead of the real `java` binary.