# JAVA_OPTS in jenkins k8s deployment, does not seem to take into account -Xss (stack size)

Tags: java, jenkins, kubernetes

In my `jenkins` deployment (for which I am using the official helm [chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins)

```
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
          value: |
            -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.PodTemplate.connectionTimeout=180 -Dhudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.initialDelay=0 -Xss512k
```

but when I log in to the pod:

```
jenkins@jenkins-cd-5f4b845c5d-cd877:/$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
```

why the `-Xss512k` has no effect and the `ThreadStackSize` remains at 1M?

Comment: Things that _run_ java to accomplish a task, like IDEs and databases and Tomcat, sometimes use `JAVA_OPTS` to set options to pass _to_ java on commandline, but java itself (run directly) does not use this envvar; in addition to commandline it uses (reads and parses) `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS` since j9 (documented) and `_JAVA_OPTIONS JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` (undocumented). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts

Answer (score 0):

From Jenkins helm chart documentation [Chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins)

"Additionally, you may want to add env vars for the Jenkins container, and the JVM (master.javaOpts)."

Answer (score 0):

Because your query is showing the default JVM config rather than the one set for your Jenkins.

It is rather a self-proving way to see the affect, you can run the following to get the result, note that  the same `-Xss512k` is added to the query.

```
java -Xss512k -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize.
```

To see the actual memory configed for the Jenkins instance in the container, you might want to look at JMX (Java Management Extensions).