# Pass parameters to my application in a image done with JIB

Tags: java, docker, maven, buildpack, jib

I would like to optimize my docker image using jib.
I have been using a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk
ARG NAME
ADD $NAME app.jar
VOLUME /tmp
VOLUME /certificates

ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar app.jar
```

Now I am creating the image with  mvn compile jib:dockerBuild but would like to know how to add the JAVA_OPTIONS to my application as I did in the past in the ENTRYPOINT of my old Dockerfile.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that you are dynamically supplying an environment variable for some Java flags *at runtime* and you want your JVM to pick up the flags *at runtime*. (If your intention is to statically set the flags and bake them into the container image at image build-time, it should be done in a different way.)

Just set the desired flags in [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` or `JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736821/1701388) if Java 9+. Your JVM will automatically pick them up (although not all Java flags may not be supported with `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`).