# How to set system properties (-D) for a java application running in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, properties

I have to set a custom system property that is to be used in my application code that runs in tomcat.

Need help for the same.

OS: Linux variant

I tried setting the same with `export JAVA_OPTS="-D<prop>=value"`.

But value is not seen in `java -XshowSettings:properties -version`

This property needs to be picked up by System.getProperty("prop"); in the application code.

Comment: take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28327620/2834978

Comment: Went through the document. This is possible while using _JAVA_OPTIONS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.. Will the same be picked by tomcat as well?

Comment: I believe so since it runs on jvm

Comment: okay let me check as well..