# how to fix improperly specified vm option 'maxmetaspacesize' on MobaXterm

Tags: java, java-8, apache-flink, flink-streaming, java-11

I'm trying to start a local cluster using mobaXTerm. I'm using:

- flink 1.15.3
- MobaXterm 23.6
- jdk 11 or jdk 8 (is the same error)
- Windows 10

I registered all the environment variables correctly, but when I run the command: `./start-cluster.sh`
,the cluster does not start. Analyzing the logs I find the following message:

- `Unrecognized option: -MaxMetaspaceSize=256m`
- `Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.`
- `Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

I tried to search inside every file in the flink folder, but I can't find where this parameter is configured. Can any of you give me some advice or have you encountered the same problem?

Comment: It could stem from one of the environment variables described in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28327620/2711488) when set before running the script. But the JVM should print a message like “Picked up VARNAME” before the error message in this case…